# how to write custom InlineLexer rule for marked.js?

Tags: javascript, markdown, lexer

With [Marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) I can easily override/add/change lexer rules during implementation, and its great!
For example I can force to use space between hash sign an text to make a header like this:

```
var lexer = new marked.Lexer(options);
console.log(lexer);
lexer.rules.heading = /^\s*(#{1,6})\s+([^\n]+?) *#* *(?:\n+|$)/

console.log(marked.parser(lexer.lex('#hashtag?'), options));
//<p>#hashtag?</p>
console.log(marked.parser(lexer.lex('# heading?'), options));
//<h1 id="undefinedheading-">heading?</h1>
```

Cool!

But is there a way, to easily do same for `inlineLexer`?
Like i need to make people be able to add an images with next sequence: `%[My Image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`?
So i modified:

```
var inlineLexer = marked.InlineLexer;
inlineLexer.rules.link = /^[!%]{0,1}?\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]]|\](?=[^\[]*\]))*)\]\(\s*<?([\s\S]*?)>?(?:\s+['"]([\s\S]*?)['"])?\s*\)/;
...
```

What should I do next?
How to bind a custom inlineLexer to a marked instance?
Please show me an example of how to do this! How can I modify/add custom inline lexer rules?

Comment: Please look at this [issue](https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/504) where I posted my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've looked at the source code for marked.js to find a way of overriding parts of it in order to allow some customization of the inline lexer, without changing the library source or affecting the global marked instance or prototypes.

```
var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
var lexer = new marked.Lexer();
var parser = new marked.Parser();

var options = {
    renderer: renderer,
    gfm: true,
    tables: false,
    breaks: true,
    pedantic: false,
    sanitize: true,
    smartLists: true,
    smartypants: false
}

parser.inline = new marked.InlineLexer([], options);
parser.inline.rules = angular.copy(parser.inline.rules); // deep copy, otherwise global marked will be affected

parser.inline.rules.link = /^[!%]{0,1}?\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]]|\](?=[^\[]*\]))*)\]\(\s*<?([\s\S]*?)>?(?:\s+['"]([\s\S]*?)['"])?\s*\)/;
renderer.link =  function(href, title, text) {
    // this is the standard link renderer that can be altered if desired ...
    if (this.options.sanitize) {
        try {
            var prot = decodeURIComponent(unescape(href))
                .replace(/[^\w:]/g, '')
                .toLowerCase();
        } catch (e) {
            return '';
        }
        if (prot.indexOf('javascript:') === 0 || prot.indexOf('vbscript:') === 0) {
            return '';
        }
    }
    var out = '<a href="' + href + '"';
    if (title) {
        out += ' title="' + title + '"';
    }
    out += '>' + text + '</a>';
    return out;
}

function parse(src) {
    parser.inline.links = src.links;
    parser.tokens = src.reverse();
    var out = '';
    while (parser.next()) {
        out += parser.tok();
    }
    return out;
};

function parseText(text) {
    var lex = lexer.lex(text);
    var r = parse(lex);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I've used angular.copy() to perform a deep copy of the inline lexer rules just to be concise, and because I use angularjs, but any deep copy will be fine.

Comment: Great. I'd give it a try. But it was centuries ago. :)